# sqlite_analyzer won't open

Tags: windows, sqlite, windows-console

Recently I was hoping to be able to view the size of certain tables of my database via SQLite. I looked up how to and found I could use sqlite_analyzer, so I downloaded it off the main SQLite website, but as soon as I open it, it shuts down again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlanalyze.html) says:

> The `sqlite3_analyzer.exe` binary is a command-line utility program

So you have to open a command-line shell, i.e., a console window; typically by running `cmd.exe`. You can then execute `sqlite_analyzer` from there.